# Code-first migration is not recognising column drop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have 2 projects (one called Biz and the other WebAdmin which is the startup project).

I delete a property from the biz project model and call add-migration.  It creates the migration CS in WebAdmin but doesn't create anything for biz project changes.

I add in a dropcolumn statement by hand DropColumn("Account", "TestID") but this doesn't not get applied to the model that 'biz' is referencing.

How can I get the dropcolumn to work?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you select the right project target in the Package Manager console.